# JSF nested components with forms

Tags: forms, jsf, components

Is it considered correct to have a composite component (`compA`) that holds a form, when `compA` can itself be contained in another form (in the using page)?

```
<!-- composite -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:form id="innerForm">
        ... composite stuff
    </h:form>
</cc:implementation>

<!-- using page/component -->
<h:form id="outerForm">
    <util:compA ... />
</h:form>
```

When trying to remove nested forms, any ajax call in the composite will submit the whole form, and as has some values may not yet be filled, validation fails.

Is there any best-practice approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested forms are *always* a bad idea and will result in invalid HTML output.

A Composite Component itself is a [Naming Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) so it should not be a problem to *process* only the CC or even some parts of it. 
To prevent the whole form from being even *submitted* I would suggest PrimeFaces AJAX calls with `partialSubmit="true"`. See [*here*](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml) for reference.

If there are still problems with your AJAX calls you habe to provide the related code of your CC.